# Advantage and disadvantages of using Actor Critic over DDQN

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am new to reinforcement learning and I read about these two algorithms Actor Critic and DDQN. I found that both of these gives fairly good results. But because two algos are totally different so I want to know that where I should prefer actor critic and where DDQN should be preferred. Also what are the advantages and disadvantages of actor critic over DDQN.

Comment: Actor-critic is not an algorithm, it's a class of algorithms. DDQN is an actor-critic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this following image from [Deep Reinforcement Learning for Multi-Agent Systems: A Review of Challenges, Solutions and Applications](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.11794.pdf) answers your question: 
[image]